# Did I damage ignition switch, could it already have been bad, how to avoid in future?

Tags: ignition-switch

I recently asked [Is my ignition switch cleaning ok?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/81401/is-my-ignition-switch-cleaning-ok) and answers said the switch is probably faulty as copper has been revealed.

My question is did I do this, could it have been avoided or was it already like this or inevitable?   You can see a before and after of the cleaning in below pics.

Did I do something wrong like sAnd too aggressively or could this have been cleaned/avoided by lighter sanding? Was sanding even required/might tissue have done it?  On the other hand could the black stuff have become so attached to the plate that removing it would have caused the silver layer To come off anyway?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I doubt you've seriously harmed the connections. I'd recommend just filling the connector full of grease, which will make the contacts slide smoothly and keep them from getting corroded in the future, and forgetting about it.

Comment: Nice job. Sometimes you may need to make index scratch marks to help reassembly. Also, I recommend adding silicone dielectric grease. Plus, use nylon cable ties if you had to drill out any rivets. This applies to other switches, not just automotive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanding was obviously too aggressive.  I recently fixed several switches by spraying them with [DeoxIT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HNV7WI2).  You don't even have to disassemble the switch, just spray & soak!

Comment: Yeah my bad.  I followed a guide where the guy suggested disassembly and sanding however after doing it I though I could have just soaked and cleaned it.  Do I need to use a product like detox or can I just soak in hot water, soap, washing up liquid etc?  Thanks.

Comment: @James Wilson - Soapy water won't cut it.  The DeoxIT works miraculously!

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can likely fix your mistake by covering the bare copper with solder.